# Laravel - Illegal offset type in AuthManager.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use middleware in the laravel routes but when I use the auth middleware the following error shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6KGb.png
in my web.php i have 
`Route::get('/','Pages\GenericPagesController@get_index')->middleware('auth');` 
in config/auth.php i had to uncomment the providers -> users section because my table name is different than the usual users

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
     'users' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'users',
     ],
],
```

Comment: I freshly installed a new laravel project

Answer (score 12):

For people who came here for a solution for lumen :

uncomment the following in bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to comment the

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\User::class,
],
```

The `providers` now is an array that has the values with same `key`. If you don't use the `eloquent` you can comment it or just rename it. Hope this can help. By the way, you might want to check whether your default `guard` is `web` or not.