# AuthManager throws Illegal offset type error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication, inertiajs

I don't know what happened but my app suddenly started throwing `Illegal offset type` when I try to log in as admin. The error happens when the authentication is successful and I'm redirected to this route:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as' => 'admin.',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']
], function () {
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

The error happens before `HomeController` is accessed. This function from **`AuthManager`** throws the error (I've added a debug log line):

```
public function guard($name = null)
{
    
    \Log::info($name);
    
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name); // line 69, error happens here
}
```

which logs this in **`laravel.log`**:

```
[2022-10-12 15:07:55] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO: array (
)  
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.ERROR: Illegal offset type {"userId":20,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Illegal offset type at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:69)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(164): Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager->guard(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#1 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(162): auth(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#2 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Middleware.php(88): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Inertia\\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#12 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(703): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(667): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#21 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(656): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#40 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php(16): require_once('/Users/artur/Ph...')
#43 {main}
"} 
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.ERROR: Target class [admin] does not exist. {"userId":20,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [admin] does not exist. at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(756): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('admin')
#1 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(860): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('admin', Array, true)
#2 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(692): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('admin', Array)
#3 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(845): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('admin', Array)
#4 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('admin')
#5 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(203): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#6 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#7 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php(16): require_once('/Users/artur/Ph...')
#8 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"admin\" does not exist at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:875)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(875): ReflectionClass->__construct('admin')
#1 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(756): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('admin')
#2 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(860): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('admin', Array, true)
#3 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(692): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('admin', Array)
#4 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(845): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('admin', Array)
#5 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('admin')
#6 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(203): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#7 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#8 /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/amresmiriel.de/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php(16): require_once('/Users/artur/Ph...')
#9 {main}
"} 
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:   
[2022-10-12 15:07:58] local.INFO:
```

I've tried looking into this error ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141064/laravel-illegal-offset-type-in-authmanager-php), [#2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/illegal-offset-type), [#3](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/illegal-offset-type-while-updating-model)) but none of the solutions provided seem to help.

As requested `/config/auth.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

The error notion `Target class [admin] does not exist.` is weird because it is registered in **`Kernel.php`** (and I've been using it all the time):

```
 protected $pathMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Which is line 69? And what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: `return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);` is line 69. I've used laravel `9.19` when the error ocurred, then updated to `9.35.1` but it didn't fix the error.

Comment: What do you have in auth.php for defaults.guard?

Comment: @aynber I've added it to the post. Default guard is `web`. If I'd put the `log` command before the error line, it would log `web` instead of `empty`.

Comment: I'm not sure, then. You might also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502196/laravel-auth-middleware-throws-illegal-offset-type-exception

Comment: @aynber I've added information on `admin` middleware, which might be the cause of the problem. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

App\Http\Kernel.php is different between 9 and 10 Laravel Version. There is a break change. You must verify this point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).